# Effective Strategies for debugging websites on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, debugging, safari

When you receive an issue about your website not functioning on an iPad, what effective strategies do you use to debug the issue?

For example, a user mentioned that a website I maintain is not accessible on his iPad.  We were able to look at his iPad and noticed all the HTML/CSS had rendered, but the Javascript component did not.  The only data I was able to capture about his iPad was that he was on iOS 8.1.2 and his User Agent was: `UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4`

Because I do not have the device to continue testing, I used [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/) to try and recreate the issue.  I emulated every iPad version that BrowserStack had and the javascript component rendered fine on all of them.

I also reached out to other people who owned iPads (v1 and v2) with iOS 8.1.2 installed and asked them to try to reproduce the issue.  It also worked fine on their iPad.

How can I reproduce this issue so that I can effectively debug it?

Comment: Does that particular iPad display run JS for other sites without any problems?

Comment: I sent him instructions on how to ensure JS was enabled and he said it was.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easily possible to use the safari remote debugging features in order to debug a website on an iOS device. 
Note: This only applies when using a Mac

Hav a look here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ios-debugging/

Comment: That would be a great tool to use.  However, I'm having a problem finding a device that can recreate the issue.  Any advice there?

Comment: While I can only guess why these problems occur on you specific device, it may help to use the ios simulator which comes with xcode. It lets you simulate almost every iOS device with different iOS versions.